# Data-binding using KO into a text box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, textbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I'm trying to place a knockout data-binding attribute to my text box- which is using bootstraps 3.0.0 class with no luck.

Any suggestions?

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" data-bind="text: customerData.firstName" 
                   class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name"/>
      </div>
```

Thank you in advance for an suggestions!

**note** I know the data-bind works because I can see the correct data displayed when the data-binding attribute is removed from the input tag.

Comment: Any chance for a fiddle?

Comment: sure thing- it doesnt work in there either..http://jsfiddle.net/WGA4z/3/

Comment: That's the point.  It gives everyone else something that is immediately debuggable which reproduces the error.  Otherwise everyone has to individually repeat the first steps.

Comment: good first effort on a fiddle, but you haven't really reproduced this issue.  You need the bootstrap and knockout libraries added to the fiddle.  Here's a [bootstrap template](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/) to get you started. Then add the knockout library by going to external resources on the left panel

Comment: I've tried adding knockout-3.0.0.js as well as just knockout.js and it says that it's not found. I apologize- i'm still very new to coding.

Comment: Use a CDN: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js

Comment: I am pretty sure the bootstrap 3 classes will not cause any issues with knockout and databinding.. I'd probably look more closely at whether you're databinding properly. For example, in your fiddle, you are binding to something called customerData.firstName, yet customerData is null. Is this data from your actual code?

Comment: Sorry guys, no dice :/

Comment: it is- but like i said- when i remove the data-bind from the input tag- im able to get the correct data

Comment: Just to clarify: The CDN should be used in the fiddle

Comment: Why would somebody downvote a question? I'm still very new, to the point that I'm trying to learn how to interact with jfiddle. Cool community.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing some things from your fiddle. Have a look at this one to get an idea as to how you can get this working.

You always need to apply the bindings
`ko.applyBindings(new MyFunction(data));`

http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/LN3ZQ/2/

Comment: I'd recommend signing up for a PluralSight subscription - they even have a free, 10 day trial or something like that. In a couple days of watching videos you'll know plenty about Knockout, which might be the best thing to happen to front end dev since jQuery. (I don't work for PS).

Comment: Thank you, really though. Your help is deeply felt, Mark!